# Getting ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version

Tags: sql, mysql

So my query is

```
CREATE TABLE POSITION(
    ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    NAME CHAR(2) NOT NULL
);
```

and if i try to run this creation i receive

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'POSITION(

But if a run the same query with POSITIONS or POSITION, it works fine.

Any idea why this happens?

I wanna know why i cant make a query with 'CREATE TABLE POSITION' on mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POSITION() is a function (an alias for LOCATE).

Since MySQL's parser interprets position as a function, you either need to add a blank after POSITION

```
CREATE TABLE POSITION (
    ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    NAME CHAR(2) NOT NULL
);
```

or if IGNORE_SPACE sql mode is set, you have to put the table name in backticks:

```
CREATE TABLE `POSITION`(
    ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    NAME CHAR(2) NOT NULL
);
```

POSITION is **not a reserved word**, since it can be used as a column name.

See also: [Function name parsing](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/function-resolution.html)